# Python web app running on django with cPanel showing error: page not found

Tags: python, django, cpanel

I didn't face this issue 1 month ago, all of a sudden my web app shows this error when I go to a particular page.

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://database.opticscouting.com/admin/users/player/1/change/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.change_view
Using the URLconf defined in opticdb.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
[name='login']
logout/ [name='logout']
password-change/ [name='password_change']
dashboard/ [name='dashboard']
player/<int:pk>/ [name='player']
favorites/ [name='favorites']
favorite/<int:pk>/ [name='favorite']
The current path, player/1/change/, didn't match any of these.
```

The python version running on the site is 3.3.7.

The error log looks like this:

```
App 633453 output: /opt/passenger-5.3.7-4.el6.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
App 633453 output: import sys, os, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
App 633453 output: [ pid=633453, time=2020-06-27 15:18:00,715 ]: Not Found: /admin/users/player/1/change/
```

Answer (score 0):

The path `player/1/change/` doesn't actually match any of your urls. The error in the log you are getting is just warning you that the **imp** module is deprecated.